# How to render content of .phtml in controller and observer in magento

Tags: magento, renderer

I have an observer `"checkout_cart_add_product_complete"`

I want to render the content of `cart.phtml` in observer and controller which is located in `/template/ajaxminicart/checkout/cart.phtml`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following,

```
<?php
$newBlock =Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('checkout/cart')
->setTemplate('ajaxminicart/checkout/cart.phtml')
-->toHtml();
echo $newBlock;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dushyant Joshi

i want to increare answer ratings but i dont have enough reputation poins.

Thanks a lot....